# JUnit 4: Nested tests

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a data transformation class which I want to test. The interface ITransformer is given. The class looks like this:

```
public class MyDataTransformer implements ITranformer {

    public MyDataTransformer() {}

    @Override
    public void init(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 0)
            throw (new Exception("bad input"));

        // do initialization
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] transform(byte[] input) {
        try {
            return transform_internal(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] transform_internal(byte[] input) throws Exception {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And this is the test class I currently have:

```
public class TransformerTest {

    private MyDataTransformer transformer;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        String[] args = new String[4];
        // set args

        try {
            transformer = new MyDataTransformer();
            transformer.init(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testTransform() {
        byte[] input = read_input(); // omitted here for brevity

        byte[] output = transformer.transform(input);
        // this only tests if "valid" data was returned, but does not look into it
        assertNotNull("Transformation failed", output);

        // these 2 test some properties of the result data and should be separate tests
        assertTrue("transformation step 1 failed", test_transformation_1(output);
        assertTrue("transformation step 2 failed", test_transformation_2(output);
    } 
}
```

There are two things I struggle with when it comes to testing.

First, how do I properly test the `init` method only once? Semantically, init belongs into the `@BeforeClass` block, but this block is not a proper test.

Second, how can I separate `test_transformation_1` out into its own test, yet make sure that this is run only after the `testTransform` completed successfully (otherwise it is not sensible to run this test on invalid input).

To me, it feels like nesting tests would solve both problems, hence the title of the question. This example however may grow and I might add independent tests which do not need nesting and I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Tests should be written in such a way that there is no dependency between them.

Comment: I know, but there clearly is a dependency and I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: It seems that you're concerned about more than one test failing if you mess up with the input and make it invalid. Why? What's the problem in having multiple tests failing? Anyway, JUnit 5 supports nested tests if you really want that. You can also just create multiple test classes.

Comment: As far as I know, the order of tests is not guaranteed. So even when `testTransform` is successful, if `test_transformation_1` is a separate test and run before that, it would fail anyway. I don't care how many tests fail, but I care about that all preconditions are met (and a precondition for `test_transformation_1` is that `testTransform` returned something non-null.

Comment: That's something you impose to yourself, and which goes against testing best practices. Tests must not depend on each other. When writing a test, just pretend that no other test exists. Each test must be able to run in isolation. So if a test method needs some input, create that input in the test method itself, or by calling another method creating the input from the test method, or using an `@Before` method. f two separate tests end up using the same input, and the input is incorrect, then it's a good thing that these two tests fail: they should, since their input is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that "semantically" it belongs into BeforeClass?! Semantically, testing the expected behavior of any method belonging to your class under test... belongs into a **test** method. Not into methods that prepare resting.

A *meaningful* init method would need to receive per test case setup data. So, if at all, you would have a field *MyDataTransformer underTest* that gets init'ed in a @Before method. With parameters that later allow proper testing.

Testing that the init method behaves as expected and throws up belongs into a distinct, nicely named @Test method.

Beyond that, you can force Junit to execute test cases given some order (for example lexicographical sorted). That isn't exactly great practice, but sometimes an okay solution to such ordering issues.

Comment: This was probably a bit ill-formulated. Testing `init` belongs into its own proper test, but it just feels right to me that this init-test is run only once at the start of the whole test class (which in turn guarantees that all following tests operate on a proper initialized member). Of course, one could do initialization for all test methods separately with `@Before`, but it feels just unclean to me so duplicate that much work (especially when `init` is a expensive long running operation).

Comment: Let's put it that way: the standard junit practice is to create new instances for each and any test method. Because junit is mainly for unit test. A true unit test can't have a long running init method. Semantically, you know :-)

Comment: In other words: when you use junit as automation tool for non unit tests, then just do what makes sense and isn't too awkward.

Comment: After reading all the great input I came to the conclusion that I'm not really doing _unit_ testing. I will refactor my code to make it better testable.

Comment: @a.ilchinger I appreciate that decision, and the quick comeback! You won't regret it (improving your code I mean ;-)

Answer (score 0):

there is no link between a function called init and it should be run only once in a unit test.It could also be run before each function.

it is a bad practice to make a test depends on another,you have to separate their testing context otherwise this is gonna lead to nightmares, if a second test depends on an other, it could fail because the first one has changed the state shared between them.therefor you are slowing yourself finding the regression root cause,and even if you decide to order alphabetically your tests,what if you were many working on the same project and someone named his test differently ... you see it is also bad.

the purpose of nested classes is to group tests by domain ,hence,enhance the quality and maintainability of your test. What i see in your design is just one domain.

> Off-topic:
>   it is bad practice to throw the general Exception class, for the sake of maintainability, create a specialized one.
>   also i see a smell in your code, why do you return inside a catch,normally,you must log the exception or throw it and the return must be outside, also, to save you some headaches in the future, return an empty array instead of null.